# submit form with a tag in codeigniter using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<script>
    function sendAction(obj){                
        var action=$(obj).attr('href');   
        alert(action);
        $("#refreshForm").attr("action",action);
        document.refreshForm.submit();
    }                           
</script>
<form id="refreshForm" action="" method="post" name="refreshForm">                     
    <input type="hidden" name="slide" value="slide" id="slide" />                   
</form>       
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="about">
        <a class="mnu-about" id="about_us" onclick="sendAction(this);" href="<?php echo SITEURL ?>/about_us/"> About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On click a tag I have called sendAction function where I want to submit form. But form is not getting submitted.

Above code I written in home.php view  and on click Link I am printing print_r($_POST). but I am not getting hidden field value in controller. ]

It means form is not submitting.

Comment: Question adagadam kaadu @aarthi choudhari andariki arthem inatlu present cheyyali

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line

```
document.refreshForm.submit();
```

to

```
$("#refreshForm").submit();
```

Have a great day.

Comment: sorry for late reply.  I have tried this first $("#refreshForm").submit(); then I change it.

Answer (score 0):

WHY DO YOU WANT `onclick="sendAction(this);" href="<?php echo SITEURL ?>/about_us/"` both onclick and href. If you are submitting form onclick, remove the `href` or make it `href="#"`

To submit a form use `$("#refreshForm").submit();`

Try this this will work :

```
function sendAction(obj){                
    $("#refreshForm").submit();
}
```